# Flip edge in Equator layer but there is yellow in every edge in top layer

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

A way to solve this is to replace the flipped edge by a random block , but in my case all random block have yellow color,  so if I swap than yellow will come in middle layer, which should not come there.

I am a absolute beginner
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Replace it with a `yellow-whatever` random block anyway: the `orange-blue` edge will get to the top layer.

Then

> put the `orange-blue` edge back in its place (of course with the correct orientation), the `yellow-whatever` will get back to the top layer.

Comment: The side with the yellow pieces is the top. (The cross is white and at the bottom. The enemy gate is down. $2+2=5$.)

Comment: @Bass sorry I've edited my answer. I didn't understand the 2+2=5 part